# Nested Backbone Models/Looping on Arrays in CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, coffeescript

I'm working on creating a basic survey rails app to learn nested models. I'm using backbone-relational to relate my models.

I think I have them related correctly, but I'm struggling with displaying each of the questions in the survey. Inside my survey template I can do `@survey.get('questions').length` and that is correct, but for some reason `.each` and `for question in @survey.get('questions')` both throw an error.

I also tried the route of looping through the questions in the view itself, but that also throws an error

Any help with me getting this to work would be really appreciated!

survey_show.jst.eco Template

```
<h2><%= @survey.get('title') %></h2>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8"
        <span class="pull-right">Number Taken: <%= @survey.get('number_taken') %>/<%= @survey.get('survey_limit') %></span>
    </div>
</div>
<ul class="list-group" id="questions">
<% @survey.get("questions").each %>
<li class="list=group-item">Derp</li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

survey.js.coffee Survey Model

```
class SurveyMe.Models.Survey extends Backbone.RelationalModel

  defaults: 
    title: 'Enter survey name'
    survey_limit: 1000
    number_taken: 0
    long: false
    survey_finished: false

   urlRoot: '/surveys'

   relations = [{
     type: Backbone.HasMany,
     key: 'questions',
     relatedModel: 'SurveyMe.Models.Question'
     reverseRelation: {
        key: 'survey',
        includeInJSON: 'id'
     }
   }]
```

question.js.coffee Question Model

```
class SurveyMe.Models.Question extends Backbone.RelationalModel

   urlRoot: '/surveys'

   relations = [{
     type: Backbone.HasMany,
     key: 'answers',
     relatedModel: 'SurveyMe.Models.Answer'
     reverseRelation: {
        key: 'question',
        includeInJSON: 'id'
     }
   }]
```

survey_show.js.coffee Survey Show View

```
  class SurveyMe.Views.SurveyShow extends Backbone.View

  template: JST['templates/surveys/survey_show']

  initialize: ->
    @model.on('all', @render, this)
    @model.on('change', @alert, this)

  events: {
    'click #back': 'back'
  }

  render: ->
    $(@el).html(@template(survey: @model))
    #@model.questions.each(@addQuestion)
    this

  back: ->
    Backbone.history.navigate("surveys",true)

  alert: ->
    alert('changed titled')

  addQuestion: (question) ->
    view = new SurveyMe.Views.Question(model: question)
    @$('#questions').append(view.render().el)
```

Question View

```
class SurveyMe.Views.Question extends Backbone.View

  template: JST['templates/surveys/question']

  tagName: 'li'

  className: 'list-group-item'

  events: 
    'click': 'edit'

  edit: ->
    Backbone.history.navigate("questions/#{@model.get('id')}",true)

  initialize: ->
    @render

  render: ->
    $(@el).html(@template(question: @model))
    this
```

Question Template

```
<%= @question.get('title') %>
<span class="pull-right"><%= @question.get('answers').length %></span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I was missing the colon at the end. So this got me what I wanted:

```
<ul class="list-group">
<% for question, i in @survey.get("questions"): %>
    <li class="list-group-item">
        <%= @survey.get("questions")[i]["title"] %>
        <ul class="list-group">
            <% for answer, j in @survey.get("questions")[i]["answers"]: %>
            <li class="list-group-item">
                <%= @survey.get("questions")[i]["answers"][j]["title"] %>
            </li>
            <% end %>
        </ul>
    </li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```